# How to transfer a static ip to another gcloud project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-networking

I would like to move a static IP from one google-cloud project to another. I must retain the same IP. I found nothing in the documentation. Is this possible?

Current status:
A static IP already exists in *project-a*. I want to transfer this IP to *project-b*.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with certainty.

In theory you could release it from project A then try to get it by requesting tons of external IP addresses in project B and hoping you catch it before someone else does (at which point you'd assign it to the desired resource and release the rest), but I wouldn't count on it.

Why must you have the same static IP? There's likely another way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: Imagine this scenario: You have a critical web service running for a client. They're constantly adding new data to their database. You can afford a downtime of a couple minutes (tops half an hour) on a low activity time-frame. If you want to migrate it, you need to propagate the DNS with the new IP, and you have no guarantees it will suffice. If you could move the IP, the only downtime is the one produced by Google on migration. Maintaining both servers online in the propagation may cause a serious headache if data is complex enough. There are workarounds, of course, but non of them is pretty.

Comment: I've to split a big project into several small projects and this is making me think a lot more than it should.

Comment: You're assuming that the cutover of an IP from one VM to another would be instant; this cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: Alex, it is much faster, and as long as you keep care with routing, the worst scenario is to make aditional hops. Not a big deal, compared to completly loosing access, dont you think?

Comment: @DGoiko Re "If you want to migrate it, you need to propagate the DNS with the new IP, and you have no guarantees it will suffice"... this is what DNS TTLs are for. Change the TTL to a very low value (say 60 seconds), then wait at least as long as the old TTL was, then perform your cutover using nothing but DNS. Problem solved.

Comment: It's not instant, though. 60 seconds is a very long time in a real world scenario. And you're asumming that a delay is admisible while the client refreshes the resolution after a failure, which is not allways the case. As I said, there are scenarios where you just cannot afford changing the IP unless you have a VERY good reason to, and Google limitations are not a valid reason. Of course, if that is not a problem for your project then you solution is perfectly OK. Using lower TTLs cause unnecesary overhead and delay on some requests aswell...

Comment: First, sorry for my english, I didn't mean afford but suffer, my bad. Second, you'r purpossing kindergarden app solutions for real workd scenarios. If I tell my clients that for a minute they may or may not recieve any data, you could consider my company dead. Maybe you're used to play in GCP support with toys that don't require a high-end configuration infraestructure, but real world is by far more compolex than GCP configuration panel. I understand you try to hide the lacks of features of your company (or former company), but DNS thing is a pure workaround: We're talking about IPs here.

Comment: If changing IP would be just fine, Why should I get myself into static ip problems? I could use a ephemeral with a dynamic dns and change IP whenever I want without problems: that not what the guy was asking. He wanted (you don't really care why) to maintain his IP. The answer is: NO, you can't, unless you have a bunch of luck and get the same IP assigned. You are the one who's trolling with offtopics.
GCP is fine to toy around. Hardware meets any high end requeriments, but the platform's software doesnt: An example, they billed us 700 K on voice transcription due to a bug in their panels.

Comment: when we just spent like 20 K or so.

Comment: So today, For some reason I stopped my VM instance and tried to restart it. But I was unable to do so because of this error -  The zone 'asia-south1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.

I tried to start the VM instance for about 6 hours but no luck and I was left with no option to clone the VM in another zone and felt wanted to assign the same static IP to another instance in another zone, but apparently this can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

Hi lately you can change static ip from one project to other using those three dots when you create a new static ip in ip addresses [image]

Comment: but make sure you set up quota limit for it